# Kotlin script: main function does not get called locally, unlike in online judge

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-script

I am trying to participate in online [Codeforces](https://codeforces.com/) contests using Kotlin.

My understanding is I should use Kotlin script if my code is contained within a single file.

If I run the following file locally (version `1.6.10`):

```sh
kotlin just_main.main.kts
```

```kotlin
// just_main.main.kts
fun main() {
    println("Hello World")
}
```

Nothing happens. I need to add an explicit call for it to actually execute `main`:

```kotlin
// top_level_call.main.kts
fun main() {
    println("Hello World")
}

main()
```

So far, so normal. The problem occurs when I try to submit my solution to the Codeforces online judge. The judge expects no top-level code and runs the main function instead. So `just_main` runs fine, but `top_level_call` produces a compilation error:

```
Can't compile file:
program.kt:43:1: error: expecting a top level declaration

main()

^
```

**This leads to the awkward situation of me having to add the `main()` call when I want to try my solution locally, but having to remove it every time I upload an attempt.**

Is there a way to have my local Kotlin behave the same as the online judge, meaning implicitly running any main functions (meaning `just_main` would produce output)?

Comment: AIUI, Kotlin script is not just about keeping all the code in one file; it's also about simpler distribution and changes and execution, at the cost of time taken to recompile before every execution. That has some knock-on effects on the way programs are written, as you've discovered!

Comment: My sad workaround is now coding my solution in a `.kts` file (because unlike `.kt` files it has proper highlighting and intellisense in IntelliJ), then running a bash command which copies it to a `.kt` file then compiles and runs it.

Comment: I think a good number of us here could attest to IntelliJ having proper code highlighting, formatting, completion, refactoring, &c for `.kt` files! If you're not getting that, then there's likely to be a problem with the way your project and/or IntelliJ is set up. (For example, is your file in a designated source folder known to IntelliJ, and/or to Maven/Gradle if those are used?)

Comment: I am using my competitive programming folder as the project. A path to an individual file looks like `./2022/cf_1647__777_2/a.kt`. My hypothesis is that IntelliJ can't deal with a project made up of independent individual scripts and expects some sort of Maven/Gradle integration.

Comment: If I might add: When hovering over variable definitions, it gives the type of `ERROR` in .kt while it shows the correct type in .kts -- no idea why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to do this with Kotlin script files, but **you can also use normal `.kt` files without having any classes in the file** (my understanding is that Kotlin magically turns them into Java class bytecode/files):

```sh
kotlinc a.kt && kotlin AKt < a.in
```

This "runs" `a.kt` with standard input from `a.in`.

(And yes I only found this after I already wrote the question)